# How to make formula that references D1 in column A for 10 rows (A1:A10) then D2 to A11:A20, etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The image below is what I what to be done where in column A the formula uses column D as a reference, copying each entry in column d for 10 consecutive rows until using all values found in column D.

[image: What I want to be automatic]

Comment: `=INDEX(D:D,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D:D)*10)/10,0))`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9cJc.png. Or `=INDEX($D$1:$D$26,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/10,0))` for prior to Excel 365.